# Why is razor not generating the expected output?

Tags: razor

```
foreach (var m in Model.Roles.ToList())
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label(m.Id, m.Name)
        @Html.CheckBox(m.Id, m.Selected, new {id = @m.Id })
    </div>
}
```

Where Model.Roles.ToList contains

```
Id: "5ef15ae7-7e34-4736-98cd-8c472f41869f", Name: "Administrators", Selected: false 
Id: "c11fa932-282a-4273-9cc4-ab181aca5d7a"  Name: "Users",      Selected: true 
Id: "c16f8cad-bc32-4539-b2e7-ad82726946b6"  Name: "Developers",     Selected: false
```

and the following output is generated:

```
    <div>
        <label for="">Administrators</label>
        <input id="5ef15ae7-7e34-4736-98cd-8c472f41869f" name="5ef15ae7-7e34-4736-98cd-8c472f41869f" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="5ef15ae7-7e34-4736-98cd-8c472f41869f" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="c11fa932-282a-4273-9cc4-ab181aca5d7a">Users</label>
        <input checked="checked" id="c11fa932-282a-4273-9cc4-ab181aca5d7a" name="c11fa932-282a-4273-9cc4-ab181aca5d7a" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="c11fa932-282a-4273-9cc4-ab181aca5d7a" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="c16f8cad-bc32-4539-b2e7-ad82726946b6">Developers</label>
        <input id="c16f8cad-bc32-4539-b2e7-ad82726946b6" name="c16f8cad-bc32-4539-b2e7-ad82726946b6" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="c16f8cad-bc32-4539-b2e7-ad82726946b6" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </div>
```

You will notice the first **label for=""** has no value, but when I run the debugger there is a value for this property.  Any ideas as to what is happening?

UPDATE:  The actual problem appears to be the first id starting with "5".  If I replace that with a character, everything works as expected.  Odd bug.  I wish I knew where to report this.

Comment: I poked into the method in ILSpy.  It's using the first parameter to get model metadata from viewdata.  This is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps razor thinks it's generating a page that is HTML4 or older?  In HTML4, an id could not start with a number; it had to be an alphabetic character.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70579/37760) for a discussion of valid HTML id values.  After that, I guess we're looking at how Razor handles those rules.